# How to change values from one column with the same values, instead of blank spaces to insert -?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

```
| project_name                                                                                                                                 | slug                                                                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CiBiX                                                                                                                                        | CiBiX                                                                                                                                        |
| ICT research, campaigning, capacity building and advocacy                                                                                    | ICT research, campaigning, capacity building and advocacy
```

I have multiple columns and I couldn't go one by one to insert instead of blank spaces ' ', '-' ?

I know there is a replace function, but I couldn't find the right way to use it. 
Because I can use it for one row, but not for multiple columns?

This is what I have tried already and I am trying to get something like this.

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| project_name                                              | slug                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| ICT research, campaigning, capacity building and advocacy | ICT-research,-campaigning,-capacity-building-and-advocacy |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is also something I have tried already. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column 
But this is from what I can see only based on a row by row.

Please, remember that I want to do this in one line for multiple rows. 
Sorry, is it clearer now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET slug=REPLACE(slug, ' ', '-');
```

So it only needs to go inside a query without any quotes.